Cannot resolve prisma type error in Next.js Typescript code
I am having trouble fixing a Typescript error. Here is the code:
import { PrismaClient, dog, cat, bird } from '@prisma/client'
export type AnyPrismaClientType = PrismaClient["dog"] | PrismaClient["cat"]  | PrismaClient["bird"]

export function makePrismaFromName(name: string): AnyPrismaClientType {
    const prismaClient = new PrismaClient()
    var client;

    switch (name) {
        case "dog": {
            client = prismaClient.dog;
            break;
        }
        case "cat": {
            client = prismaClient.cat;
            break;
        }
        case "bird": {
            client = prismaClient.bird;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            const msg = `unrecognized animal type ${String(name)}`;
            throw (msg);
        }
    }

    return client;
}

const myClient = makePrismaFromName('dog');

const inactiveAnimalCount = await myClient.count( // --> This is the line giving me the type error.
    {
        where: {
            stray: false,
            clean: true,
        }
    }
);

Here is the error:
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<T extends dogCountArgs>(args?: Subset<T, DogCountArgs<DefaultArgs>> | undefined) =>
  PrismaPromise<T extends Record_2<"select", any> ? T["select"] extends true ? number : { [P in keyof T["select"]]: P extends
  keyof DogCountAggregateOutputType ? DogCountAggregateOutputType[P] : never; } : number>) | (<T ...' has signatures, but none
  of those signatures are compatible with each other.


The issue you are facing here is that all these returned types (dog, cat, or bird) are causing confusion to TS, where it isn't able to determine which type of these to use to run the count method.
The solution you're looking for is using generics with a type-safe map model. We rely on TS's natural type inferring features to correctly determine the type based on the provided parameter.
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const modelMap = {
    dog: prismaClient.dog,
    cat: prismaClient.cat,
    bird: prismaClient.bird
} as const;

type Animal = keyof typeof modelMap;


export function makePrismaFromName<K extends Animal>(name: K): typeof modelMap[K] {
    return modelMap[name];
}

Your calling function and other parts would remain the same.

Thanks, but unfortunately this does not solve the issue. I am still getting the same type error message even when using your suggestion. (Also, I fixed a small typo in my example code.)

Hey @rlandster, had overlooked something. Fixed the answer.
